# How to get height of a table without writing to document

Tags: java, openpdf

The `PdfPTable#getTotalHeight()` method returns 0 until it is written into a document. Is there a way to get the height before writing to the document?

```java
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter instance = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
document.open();

PdfPTable table = ...

System.out.println("table total height: " + table.getTotalHeight());
document.add(table);
System.out.println("after adding to doc");
System.out.println("table total height: " + table.getTotalHeight());

document.close();
```

Output in console:

```
table total height: 0.0
after adding to doc
table total height: 1249.3105
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would need that? Just create a new empty document for each height check.

Comment: @Nexarius I want to avoid writing to a document for performance reasons.

Comment: Can you make a compileable reproduceable example? I actually have received a very similar task and found this question by googling (because I actually assumed it would work like you described). However, in my case it actually works out of the box, but now I'm concerned that there might be cases where `getTotalHeight` will return zero and break my logic.

Comment: @adnan_e I answered the question just now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that without a width, the hight of the table cannot be calculated. When we add the table to a document, the width will be calculated depending on the page size, margins and the relative with of the table (by default set to 80%).

We can manually assigning a fixed width to the table with `table.setTotalWidth(...)`. The height is available immediately after that. If we want to add the table with the defined fixed with to a document, we need to lock it with `table.setLockedWidth(true)`. The width you manually set depends on where exactly you want to add the table. You need to calculate the width of the container beforehand yourself.

```java
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
document.open();

// add a table with 2 columns and 3 rows and some filler text (LOREM_IPSUM)
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.addCell(LOREM_IPSUM); table.addCell(LOREM_IPSUM);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(LOREM_IPSUM));
cell.setColspan(2); table.addCell(cell);
table.addCell(LOREM_IPSUM); table.addCell(LOREM_IPSUM);

// manually set the width (as an example to page content width)
float containerWidth = document.getPageSize().getWidth() - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin();
table.setTotalWidth(containerWidth);
table.setLockedWidth(true);

// get height of table before and after adding it to the document
System.out.println("Height before adding: " + table.getTotalHeight());
document.add(table);
System.out.println("Height after adding:  " + table.getTotalHeight());

document.close();
```

```
Height before adding: 132.0
Height after adding:  132.0
```